# Combining classes in Anypic example project

Tags: parse-platform, backend

I was going through the [Anypic tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic) and the data model part specifically because I want to build a similar app. My question is why can't I remove the permission restrictions and let the image class hold the likes (int) and the comments (array of strings) and don't allow the users of the app to edit other users images. What can be the drawbacks of this approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission restrictions are in place for security.

By separating the `likes` from the `Photo` class, it prevents other users from modifying someone else's photos. The way Parse ACLs (Access Control Lists) work is by restricting read/write access.

Let's consider the scenario that `likes` are contained within the `Photo` class. If one user wants to like someone else's photo, they will have to modify the user's photo directly, which requires write permissions in the ACL.

No big deal, right? Wrong. Someone with malicious intent could structure their own REST API calls to your app and perform whatever actions they want on other people's photos. I could remotely modify or delete your photos, spoof additional likes, and tons of other exploits depending on the rest of your app.

If you still wanted to keep `likes` within the `Photo` class, but not have public write access, then whenever someone tries to like a photo, you would have to perform the write in cloud code using the master key. You would also need to do extra validation beforehand so someone else couldn't spoof this request.

Parse ACLs are great because they are incredibly simple and quickly allow you to compartmentalize read/write access as needed within your app.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't think about the security issues involved with allowing anyone to access the class.